# ffmpeg convert image sequence to video

Tags: python, ffmpeg

image sequences start with

```
sdhdfd_plate_bg01_v001_fds_fdse_fdfd.1001
sdhdfd_plate_bg01_v001_fds_fdse_fdfd.1002
sdhdfd_plate_bg01_v001_fds_fdse_fdfd.1003
```

using

```
ffmpeg -i D:/imagesequence/sdhdfd_plate/sdhdfd_plate_bg01_v001_fds_fdse_fdfd.%04d.jpg -vf "[in]drawtext=fontsize=32:fontcolor=White:fontfile='/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf':text='shotName':x=(w)/2:y=(h)-50[out]" D:/Uss/Temp/sdhdfd_plate_bg01_v001_fds_fdse_fdfd.%04d.jpg
```

following error occurs

```
D:/imagesequence/sdhdfd_plate/sdhdfd_plate_bg01_v001_fds_fdse_fdfd.%04d.jpg: N
o such file or directory
```

is it possible to convert these type images using ffmpeg

Comment: In your sequence listing, there are no `.jpg` extensions. Do your files have them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a couple reasons why this isn't working.  First, as pointed out by pixelistik, if your images don't actually have .jpg extensions, it won't work (eg, if they're actually png or something).

Secondly, your image sequence has to start at 0 or 1, so starting at 1001 won't work.  You can use this batch code or something like it in a UNIX shell to rename your images into a workable sequence.

```
x=1; for i in *jpg; do counter=$(printf %04d $x); ln "$i" sdhdfd_plate_bg01_v001_fds_fdse_fdfd."$counter".jpg; x=$(($x+1)); done
```

Note that you must be in the directory holding the images, and if there are other images that you don't want included, you'll have to change `for i in *jpg` to something like `for i in sdhdfd_plate_bg01_v001_fds_fdse_fdfd.*`.

Answer (score 0):

1. seems pattern does not work under windows.
2. your pattern is incorrect,

for files:

```
sdhdfd_plate_bg01_v001_fds_fdse_fdfd.1001.jpg
sdhdfd_plate_bg01_v001_fds_fdse_fdfd.1002.jpg
sdhdfd_plate_bg01_v001_fds_fdse_fdfd.1003.jpg
```

the input pattern should be:

```
sdhdfd_plate_bg01_v001_fds_fdse_fdfd.1%03d.jpg
```

here the `1%03d` mapping to:  `1001`, `1002`, `1003`...